# Change Product Price if particular Payment Gateway is selected

Tags: product, price, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I have 2 payment gateway on the website, I want when user choose payment gateway one, price of all products gets increased by 10

I new to magento and could not find with an event to override for this please help me with a way for same

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement looks a bit weird. Because payment gateway selection comes on checkout page. If you change product price once customer chooses payment gateway then customer might feel weird as well and it also require to change all cart totals in such case. This might lead to heavy bounce rate from checkout page on your website as well.

Rather, I would suggest you to add/apply some kind of fixed/percentage extra fee to the cart totals if customer chooses selected payment gateway. That will make some sense and your checkout flow will be easy to understand for your customers.

There are some third party extensions also available on magento marketplace which applies extra fee on selected payment gateways. You can review those.

Thanks,

Comment: can you help with way to that like adding 100 ruppee extra to total if payment gateway changes

Comment: You need to develop whole custom logic to achieve this. You can track payment method selection event on checkout and can apply custom total using it. There are also ready made extension (https://magecomp.com/magento-2-payment-fee.html) available for this which you can use directly in your project.